# How can I resolve a proxy error for Cloud Foundry?

Tags: proxy, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I want to push changes to the application hosted on IBM Cloud using CLI. When I try to login I have a proxy error

```
PS C:\Users\user1\folder1\myapp> cf login
API endpoint: https://api.eu-de.bluemix.net

API endpoint:   https://api.eu-de.bluemix.net (API version: 2.128.0)
Not logged in. Use 'cf login' to log in.
FAILED
Error performing request: Get https://login.eu-de.cf.cloud.ibm.com/UAALoginServerWAR/login: Proxy Authentication Required
```

I set environnement variables HTTPS_PROXY and HTTP_PROXY: http://XXXXXX.XXX:1234

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Try to use `ibmcloud login` and then the `ibmcloud cf` commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the **https://api.eu-de.cf.cloud.ibm.com** API endpoint instead. While **mybluemix.net** should continue to work, **bluemix.net** should usually be replaced with the **cloud.ibm.com** equivalent.

Comment: You are right. Now IBM redirects from bluemix.net to cloud.ibm.com. Here is the official announce: https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/permanent-redirect-to-cloud-ibm-com-from-console-bluemix-net

Comment: I added *.cloud.ibm.com in the white list for proxy. Now it works, thank you